# How best to give up a dog for adoption?

Tags: dogs, safety, aggression

We have a pit bull just over 1 year old.  Because we now have children we feel it best to not have the dog, though we (the parents) love him.  We do not want the dog “put down”.
How best can we put the dog up for adoption but ensure that the dog is not “put down”?

Comment: Where in the world are you? Even a continent would help :)

Comment: North America, USA, Texas, Dallas

Comment: I think this question really depends on the dog. May he be aggressive or dangerous around children? Is he well trained? Any medical problems? etc. While most shelters and rescues try to do whatever they can to avoid euthanising, in some cases it may be the only humane option. You need to contact local rescue groups to see what their policies are regarding euthanasia.

Comment: @HarryV. Yes, this dog may become aggressive.  I will take your advice on who to contact.

Comment: If you have some time, you yourself could search for a new home...

Comment: The questions sounds odd... Is there an actual problem with the dog or are you just afraid that he may become a problem in the future? Just because a dog is a pit bull doesn't automatically make him a problem dog. Pit bulls can be very gentle family dogs if raised and trained well. And at 1 year or age he's still quick to adapt and learn new rules like "don't lick the baby".

Comment: @Elmy The dog has snipped at a child. There has been an attempt to train him with minor improvement. Pit bulls are in the top 4 dog breeds that bite people. Some studies put the pit bulls at most likely to bite, just ahead of German shepherds. So, ‘yes’ this has now become a concern for the near future.

Comment: I am not in USA, but in my local area, it usually helps if you offer some help to whoever might want to take care of him. It should never be cash help, because it would attract predators. It could be more like help with the vet fees and some help with the dog food. If you contact with the new vet regularly, you'll also know if your dog is treated well. This might not be fiscally ideal but it would increase the odds in favour of your dog tremendously

Comment: @C.Koca That’s a very good point. I’m glad you brought that up.